# Check if image background is simple or complicated python3

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have set of real pictures. Is there a way to check if the background is a simple color or a complex/ complicated background using python3?

2 types of images:

- Simple background as human see it as 1 color but because of the lighting, each pixel values are different:

[image: Background is 1 color with some lighting gradient]
[image]

- Complicated/ Complex background

[image]
[image]

I tried many methods but none of them works:

- colors counter. Because of lightings and shades, each pixel color values are different.
- pixel variance.
- colors bin
- color quantize

Comment: I think the most difficult part of this will be determining what is the foreground and what is the background. How about setting the "background" of your images to the pixels within a certain range of the borders of your images? Then you could perhaps convert the background to grayscale and compare the variances of the grayscaled backgrounds? Or put the backgrounds through laplacian filters and compare the variances of those?

Comment: I think the most difficult part of this will be determining what is the simple/complicated image.

Comment: @Tyson: That's a good idea to separate background and foreground. I'll try that out. There are background remover that give me the foreground content on transparent background.

Comment: @Leox: I don't know how to determine simple/complicate image yet. I was hoping to set a threshold at some calculated value. For now, as a human seeing it, simple background is 1 color background with varies of lightings and shades. Complicated background is the real life stuffs like trees, roads, or multiple colors. The whole point is that: I have a background removal function that return foreground on transparent background. I need to know if I need to use black or white background to replace it. Do you have any good ideas on how to determine simple/ complex image?

Comment: Your comparison method should allow you to sort your image backgrounds from less complex to more complex. To set the threshold as to what constitutes "simple" and what constitutes "complex", you could find a set of images that you (or your customers?) determine to be "simple" and "complex", run those images through your algorithm, and use those numbers as your threshold.